# Import block data of a text file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, data-manipulation, text-manipulation

Suppose I have a simple text file named "**test.txt**" of the format below

```
A=-1.1,2.2,-3.3,4.4B
```

My intention is to extract data **-1.1**, **2.2**, **-3.3** and **4.4** in Matlab from the text file.

How could I do that?

**Ps: Note that the data is between a string "A =" and "B" and is separated by a comma.**

I managed to extract the first data with the code below.

```
buffer = fileread('test.txt');
search = 'A=';
local = strfind(buffer, search);
value = sscanf(buffer(local(1,1)+numel(search):end), '%f', 1);
```

However, I'm not sure how to get the other values from the list that end in the string **"B"**

Comment: Are you looking for a function like [`textscan`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)? It is designed for handling inputs with specific formats like those. For example, you would use something like `textscan(string,"%*c %*c %f %f %f %f %*c", 'delimiter', ',')`.

Comment: I was not sure how to put the delimiter, thanks @mimocha

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is my answer:

```
clear; clc

path = 'test.txt';
fileID = fopen(path, 'r');
A = fscanf(fileID, '%s');
splitStr = regexp(A, '[a-zA-Z]', 'split');
splitStr = regexp(splitStr, '=', 'split');
splitStr = regexp(splitStr{2}, ',', 'split');
disp(splitStr{2})
fclose(fileID);
```

Output:

```
'-1.1'    '2.2'    '-3.3'    '4.4'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context either as comments with the code or as a separate paragraph regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.